# Webpage loading stuck on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer

we notice some strange behaviour on Internet Explorer 8.
Sometimes our Page (Intranet) starts loading but is not going to finish completly, the IE8 Loading spinner is running forever and the JavaScript of the page is not executed. HTML / CSS is displaying as it should. We use JavaScript (Prototype) to do some stuff and this is not executed. If you hit reload it works.

On FF / Chrome it works like it should.

So how to debug this one? Im not quite sure if its a JS Problem. (We dont get any errors). Seems to me the IE8 is waiting for some response which is not answered by the server.

JS is fired with Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', .....

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should consider watching the HTTP traffic with a network debugger like www.fiddler2.com

Answer (score 0):

The way I typically debug situations like these is to put alert messages after each step in the code, in the order it is supposed to execute. More often than not, the alerts fire in sequence till the troublesome area has been reached. That's when I am able to atleast narrow down on which section of the code is causing the problem.